# How to use different fonts for different browsers

Tags: css, html

I faced a problem using fonts via `@font-face`: Chrome ignores `font-weight` rule with this font, so captions look poor. Searching made no results in my case. So I found another version of my font to use it with Chrome.

Can you tell me the simplest way to set another font for headers only in this browser?

Comment: *Chrome ignores `font-weight`* - Are you serious? `:O`

Comment: @PraveenKumar only with my font. I found out it's popular problem but google didn't help me fix it

Comment: @PraveenKumar Pragmatica

Comment: Does that font have the glyphs for various `font-weight`s?

Comment: I can find it [better](https://typekit.com/fonts/pragmatica-web). Chrome 50. FYI.

Comment: @PraveenKumar and so what? Read my question one more time: I already got that font and I need to apply it for headers in Chrome

Comment: Er... I don't understand yet.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Everything is okay with FF but Chrome ignores font-weight and headers in this browser look like just big common text. I got other version of that font and want to use it only with headers in Chrome.

Comment: A JSFiddle would help. Your question says it's a font weight problem, but the comment above suggests the entire font is being ignored. Have you double-checked the path to the font in the @font declaration? Some browsers can still find it with a bad path, but some are less forgiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a style specifically for the browser, the easiest solution is to use javascript to detect the browser and write the browser name to the body tag on the page as a classname. Then you can use the classname to control CSS for that browser.

[Here's a jsFiddle that detects Chrome.](https://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/gNENk/)

But your question might be able to be better solved without adding an extra script and markup.

Double-check your font path. Some browsers will still find the font, some are more picky:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'your-font-name';
  src: url('/fonts/your-font-name.woff2') format('woff2'), /* check path */
     url('/fonts/your-font-name.woff') format('woff'); /* check path */
  font-weight: normal; /* if this is being ignored, try declaring it in the h1 */
  font-style: normal;
}
```

If you've declared "font-weight: normal;" in your @font declaration, and it's being ignored, for some browsers you need to create an additional rule for the h1 style:

```
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: No, Chrome ignores bold `font-weight` in headers, not `normal`. But it doesn't solve my problem anyway. I already checked paths too. Seems like I have to use js. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for script! I add another css for Chrome only and it works. Unfortunately it's crutch.